# When I try to open the MyForm.h [Design] it just shows and error, I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I open the MyForm.h[Design] it shows the error:
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

1 Error

The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.

Instances of this error (1)

1. Hide Call Stack

at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

If anyone can help me that would be much appreciated! I have tried to look online for the issue but I was unable to figure out how to fix it.